# When does a function have an inverse?

Tags: functions, inverse

I have been told that a function has an inverse if it is one-to-one or injective, but how can we rigorously prove this?  I have been struggling to find a proof for days.

Comment: Well, if it is not one-to-one, then the inverse function can map a given $f(x)$ to several possible $x$'s - in which case it is not, by definition, a function.

Comment: If you have been struggling with a proof for days, then surely you have some thoughts of your own on the matter? What is tripping you up? Also, one-to-one and injective are different terms for the same thing. Did you mean an injective and surjective function has an inverse?

Comment: Suppose you have a function $f(x)=x^2$. The function $f$ will square the value of $x$ (you put in) and give you as output similarly the inverse of the function $f$ denoted as $f^{-1}$ will give you the square root of $x^2$. Lets take $x=2$ we have $f(x)=4$ and similarly we have $f^{-1}(2^2)=2$

Comment: @SufyanNaeem The mapping $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ is *not* one-to-one (e.g., $f(-2)=4=f(2)$).

Comment: @MagicMan I have answered just to the **title**

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function $f\colon X\subset\mathbb{R}\to Y\subset\mathbb{R}$, the definition of inverse function is some $g$ such if $\color{red}{f(x)=y\Rightarrow g(y)=x\mbox{ or }f\circ g= g\circ f =id}$

How to get this? suppose that there are $x_1,x_2\in X$ such $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y_0$ then the "inverse function $g$" what would do with $g(y_0)$? this is why we need $f$ be inJective (or one-to-one)

Then if we have some $y_1\in Y$ such no exists some $x\in\ X$ with $f(x)=y_1$ what should we do with $g(y_1)$? That's why we need $f$ be surjective.

$\therefore$ We need $f$ be bijective.

Comment: You have got that backwards. The question is "why one-to-one and surjective $\implies$ has an inverse". You have proven "has an inverse $\implies$ one-to-one and surjective".

Comment: oh, i read "when a function has a inverse" and I tried to ilustrate what needs a function for have a inverse.

Comment: or maybe I didn't understand your comment because I am bad in english as you can read :(

Comment: Coloring it all red was just so redundant.. If you use it, then use it to convey some information.

Comment: @user31415 I don't see how it was *redundant* to use color--I don't think it was necessary, but how was it redundant?

Comment: @MagicMan It mainly seemed like a way to show off your latex skills, and it fairly objectively doesn't look fancy (if that's what he intended) too. You say it was unnecessary, and indeed the definition of _redundant_ is "Not or no longer needed or useful". It added no value and he just colored everything. It's not like some other users do it, like e.g. Bill Dubuque ([here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1250571/107671) just for one example).

Comment: @user31415 I don't know where you're getting your definitions, but that's a poor definition of redundant that you used. A much better one is as follows: "characterized by verbosity or unnecessary repetition in expressing ideas; prolix." What you described may be more aptly characterized as "obsolete." Regardless, there are no "$\rm\LaTeX$ skills" being showed off here. We can both agree the color is unnecessary, and I honestly think B.D. uses it *way* too much. To each his own though.

Answer (score 0):

> A function $f:X\to Y$ is a subset of the Cartesian product $X \times Y$ subject to the following condition: every element of $X$ is the first component of one and only one ordered pair in the subset.

Now, suppose $f$ is one to one and onto.

Consider $f^{-1}:Y\to X$, defined as $f^{-1}(y)=x \iff f(x)=y$ (or in other words, $(y,x)\in f^{-1} \iff (x,y)\in f$). Now, for every $y\in Y$, there exist at least a $x\in X$ such that $f(y)=x$ since it is onto.

Uniqueness of such ordered pair $(y,x)$ is assured by the fact that $f$ is one-one.

Hence $f^{-1}$ is clearly a function by definition.

Comment: You have got that backwards. The question is "why one-to-one and surjective $\implies$ has an inverse". You have proven "has an inverse $\implies$ one-to-one and surjective".

Comment: I see it more like not bijective $\implies$ inverse can't be a function

Comment: "$\neg P \implies \neg Q$" is the same thing as "$Q \implies P$". The question wants to know why "a function has an inverse if it is one-to-one or injective".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Works now?

Answer (score 0):

This is not "the proof" that you might be looking for, but just to help you think about it. A function $y = f(x)$ has an inverse if there exists another function $y = g(x)$ such that for all $x$ $f(g(x)) = x$ and $g(f(x)) = x$. (It is possible that only one of these formulas hold. In that case we would talk about right and left inverses.)

If a function is not injective, then there are two distinct values $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. In that case there can't be an inverse because if such a function existed, then 
$$
x_1 = g(f(x_1)) = g(f(x_2)) = x_2.
$$
Likewise, if a function is injective, then it does have an inverse defined by $g(x)$ is that unique number $x'$ satisfying that $f(x') = x$. You, of course, have to be careful about domains and ranges.